# PHP - Find the differences between multidimensional arrays, but keep the index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have theese two arrays:

$haystack

```
Array (
    [rowid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 400
            [2] => 500
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => text1
            [1] => text2
            [2] => text3
        )

    [qty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

$needle

```
Array
(
    [rowid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 500
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => newtext1
            [1] => newtext3
        )

    [qty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
            [1] => 60
        )

)
```

I want to cross haystack array (with a foreach) and find where needle["rowid"] is present or not in haystack.
I want to get something like this:

> Haystack value 200 description text1 is PRESENT in needle but modified
>   in newtext1 with qty = 50 (needle key 0) 
>   Haystack value 400 is MISSING 
>   Haystack value 500 description text3 is PRESENT in needle but modified
>   in newtext3 with qty = 60 (needle key 2)

I tried this:

```
   foreach ($haystack["rowid"] as $key => $value) :

                $result = recursive_array_search($haystack["rowid"][$key],$needle);

                if ($result) {              
                    //found the same rowid
                }
                else { 
                    //not found 
        }

    function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
            foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
                $current_key=$key;
                if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
                    return array("key" => $current_key, "value" => $value);
                }
            }
            return false; 
    }
```

But when $key = 2 (last $haystack key) $result["value"] or $result["key"] become "null" because $needle has got only 0 and 1 keys!
How can i edit the function?
Thank you very much, i'm no expert with multidimensional arrays!

Answer (score 0):

Simply solved with a new index $i :)

```
$i=0;
foreach ($haystack["rowid"] as $key => $value) :

        $result = recursive_array_search($haystack["rowid"][$key],$needle["rowid"]);

        if ($result) {              
            //found new value in $needle["description"][$i]
            $i++;
        }
        else { 
            //not found
}
```

Is there a quick method? Bye